# PL/SQL anonymous block to test a procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

pL/SQL PROCEDURE

This is the code for a procedure that takes the term,lineno,component name,student id,score as input and processes the student score.

The procedure should add the score into the scores table if there are no exceptions.

### CODE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE score_details
(aterm     IN scores.Term%type,
alineno   IN scores.Lineno%type,
acompname IN scores.Compname%type,
asid      IN scores.sid%type,   
apoints   IN scores.points%type)

AS  sterm scores.Term%type;
slineno scores.Lineno%type;
scompname scores.compname%type;
ssid scores.sid%type;
spoints scores.points%type;

BEGIN

SELECT term,lineno,compname,sid,points
INTO sterm,slineno,scompname,ssid,spoints

FROM scores

WHERE aterm=term AND alineno=Lineno AND acompname=compname AND asid=sid AND apoints=points;

EXCEPTION
when no_data_found THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Invalid details');
```

### ANONYMOUS BLOCK

The below is the code for anonymous block to test the above procedure.

I'm not able to get the correct result.Please help me with the code.

```
ACCEPT   prompt 'pterm','plineno','pcompname','psid','ppoints'

DECLARE  pterm scores.Term%type;
plineno scores.Lineno%type;
pcompname scores.Compname%type;
psid scores.sid%type;
ppoints scores.points%type;

BEGIN
score_details(pterm,plineno,pcompname,psid,ppoints);

END
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you've intentionally missed out most of the body of your stored procedure, as it fetches some values out of a table into some local variables and then does nothing with these values.

I'm guessing that you're wondering why the values you entered in the `ACCEPT` line didn't make it into the stored procedure call.

`ACCEPT` is a SQL*Plus statement that you can use to set substitution variables.  The following example creates a substitution variable named `colour` and displays the result.  The line **`Yellow`** was typed in by me:

```
SQL> ACCEPT &colour
Yellow
SQL> PROMPT Your favourite colour is &colour
Your favourite colour is Yellow
```

You can also provide a prompt to the user to clarify what you're asking for:

```
SQL> ACCEPT colour PROMPT 'Enter a colour > '
Enter a colour > Yellow
```

and you can also use substitution variables in SQL:

```
SQL> select '&colour' from dual;
old   1: select '&colour' from dual
new   1: select 'Yellow' from dual

'YELLO
------
Yellow
```

It seems there's two things not quite right with your PL/SQL block at the moment:

1. Your `ACCEPT` statement isn't working.  You haven't quite got the order of the parts of it right (if used, `PROMPT` must come after the variable name).  Also, I don't think you can set more than one substitution variable in a single `ACCEPT`.
2. You're not using the substitution variables that contain the values entered.

I'd therefore imagine that you'd want the call to your PL/SQL block to look a bit more like the following:

```
ACCEPT pterm PROMPT 'Enter a term > '
ACCEPT plineno PROMPT 'Enter a line number > '
-- and similarly for the others.

DECLARE
    pterm scores.Term%type := '&pterm';
    plineno scores.Lineno%type := '&plineno';
    pcompname scores.Compname%type := '&pcompname';
    psid scores.sid%type := '&psid';
    ppoints scores.points%type := '&ppoints';
BEGIN
    score_details(pterm,plineno,pcompname,psid,ppoints);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I got your point.I run the code & got the error Error(31,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PTERM" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; .                                                 I wrote the anonymous block below the procedure. Should I write END; between procedure and anonymous block?

Comment: Your stored procedure is indeed missing an `END;` from the bottom.  You'll also need to add a single line containing only a `/`.  SQL*Plus isn't smart enough to know when a stored procedure ends, so it needs a line containing only a `/` to let it know that the current procedure has ended.